# "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE" after trying to draw an Image on Canvas

Tags: javascript

I have this Problem where whenever I try to draw an Image on Canvas I get this error message in the Console:

```
Uncaught Exception [...]
name: "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE"
result: 2147746065
```

I use HTML and Javascript.
When using the context.DrawImage(); command outside of that specific function, there is no error.
even with the same variables and numbers.

```
function rendering(dt) {
  mainContext.clearRect(0,0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);
  renderMap();
} [...]

var SpritePosX;
var SpritePosY;

//this function wont run

function renderMap() {
  SpritePosX = PlayerX + SpriteX - 100;
  SpritePosY = PlayerY + SpriteY - 100;
  sprite.onload = function () {ctx.drawImage(sprite, SpritePosX, SpritePosY, 50, 50);
}
```

Trying to draw the image from console will not work as long as the function is inside the code.
If I remove the "problematic" function it will work in the rendering function and inside of the console.
the `rendering(dt);` function is hooked up to a gameloop, everything is ok with that.
Every Variable is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an Idiot.
The code inside the rendering.js part of the project was fine,
the problem was that I made a spelling mistake while defining the source of the picture.